# Can an executable return something to another executable?

Tags: java, c++, return

In C++ one normally uses `int main(int argc, char* argv [])` afaik.
What I do not know about is, can the returned `int` be given to another .exe or .jar? For example if I got something which is easier to do in C++ for me than in Java and I want the result to be assigned to an `int` or whatever else in java?
And if not "multi-language", can this at least be done from one C++ exe to another?

Comment: What it really sounds like you need is a library, and you call that library from the other programming language(most likely using a C interface).

Comment: The value returned from `main` is given to the operating system.  You'll need to explore your operating system to see what functionality it has.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If one program launches another it can collect the exit code of the child when it terminates.

You can also have *much* more communication between two processes if you need - like setting up pipes between standard input and standard output so parent and child can send arbitrary messages by just reading/writing `cin`/`cout` or you can use sockets, UNIX domain sockets, TCP sockets, whatever, or shared memory between processes. 
Look up IPC (Inter Process Communication).

And by the way; the language(s) each application is written in does not matter. All that matters is that they are using the same IPC mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

The value returned from `main` becomes the process's exit code.  If you launch a subprocess then you'll usually be able to access that value in some way (see [the `Process` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) for Java), but it's not generally used for communicating results.  By convention the exit code is used to report success or failure: 0 means success and non-zero exit codes are used to signal various error conditions.

There are various methods for communicating from one process to another.  The simplest is generally to just write data to the subprocess's standard input stream and receive data from its standard output and standard error streams.  See [the `ProcessBuilder` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) for how you could do that in Java.  Processes can also communicate using other methods, like sockets or shared memory, but those are a larger topic.